# Multithreaded server creates multiple threads by fails to read

Tags: c#, string, multithreading, server

I  have been making a multithreaded server, I cant share much but I will tell in clear theory how it is working.
I have a server that goes in a while(true) loop and it waits for a connection. Everything works, it makes the multithreads. and the server does work when I read one at a time. However when I decide to run 10 threads, it returns and says it fails to read the message (in the cmd window).

Why is this or why could this be? I am also reading in the message by:

```
int characterNumer;
characterNumber = streamReader.read();
while(CharacterNumber > 0)
{
message += (char)CharacterNumber;
characterNumber = streamreader.read();
}
```

the second line is in a try catch statement twice so it does read. but for the server it fails. why is this?
What would you recommend or advise? It does work perfectly when it is not multithreading.

Comment: impossible to say with out seeing the full error message and code. I gues you are putting the connection info into a c# container like a dictionary or a list or something. You need to do that under lock. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock

Comment: I do have a list that I put the information to. That is outside of the class and with the main. however I call the main class and send the information into the list from the class that processes and reads the message. so I do have two different classes, one with a list and one sending information to the list

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail if you want help otherwise we can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: If you are waiting for a connection, or a trigger, why don't you use a SemaphoreSlim? that is what it is built for.

Comment: line 15
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: That is what I receive. but it clearly does connect because I message it 8 times at the same time. and it receives 8 connections. and it does read when it is one at a time but for this case, no.

Comment: semaphoreslim?.